# LUA io.read() statement makes a output blank

Tags: loops, lua, output, repeat

SO I've been following a Lua tutorial for the past two days (https://youtu.be/iMacxZQMPXs?t=1252) and I've got stuck on a repeat loop because the output is empty
here is the code:

```lua
repeat
  io.write("Enter your guess : ")
 
  guess = io.read()
 

until tonumber(guess) == 15
```

Every time I run it, it shows a blank output with no errors

The problem seems to be caused by `io.read()` But I am not sure

I also downloaded some packages if it matters: Lua Dev, BracketHighLighter, SidebarEnhancements, SublimeLinter, SubLimeLinter-Lua,

Comment: What do you mean by `makes a output blank`? the code you posted works fine for me

Comment: every time i build it the result is just blank, the code just doesn't work and there is no error I am hoping somebody had a similar issue and has found a solution

Comment: how are you "building" the code and how are you running it? there is nothing wrong with the code you posted it work as intended.

Comment: You know what I mean, I don't know the term and It's blank for me What text editor are you using? I am using Sublime

Comment: you can try your code online here for example: https://repl.it/languages/lua

Comment: Insert the following statement in the beginning of your program: `io.stdout:setvbuf('no')`

Comment: The code now Types out "Enter your guess:" But ignores my guesses So io.read still doesn't work but at least the code did run, what is that?